# SSRS 2008 R2 Freezess during authentication

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Since I upgraded to IE9 Sql Server Reporting Services freezes once the authentication window is submitted.
No matter what when a password dialog box appears if I click OK (regardless of correctness of password) the program freezes.

[image]

Ironically the password is saved with the connection, clicking "Test Connection" always works with no errors.

I've tried delete the cache and creating a new report. Also installing SSRS locally and running it as administrator. If I sniff the network traffic I see that the password is transmitted to SSRS when a report is loaded. And when I click OK no network traffic seems to get generated (Using fiddler so this might not be 100% accurate). I do not see anything in the eventviewer and I don't see any logs in Program Files.

Any ideas to correct this?

---- Edit

I decompiled SSRS. I think the crashing point must be the caching of credentials as seen here:
[image]

Comment: Pretty bizarre. If you log into ssrs manager and delete the report and redeploy do you continue to experience the problem?

Comment: Is this scenario using Visual Studio?  Exactly what are you doing to make the "authentication window" appear?

Comment: In my entire experience with SSRS the "authentication window" always reappears, once per session per datasource. Which is ironic because if you sniff the traffic the password is sent from the server to SSRS in clear text. Also since "Test Connection" works it stands to reason that the password is indeed not needed.

Comment: Instead of deleting the report I tried creating a completely new one at the point where it would seem to upload the datasource it freezes.

Comment: Deleting the report also creates the same problem. (I've also tred deleting SSRS, deleting my entire cache, installing SSRS locally, trusting the site in IE) :/

Comment: I am not using Visual Studios. I've enjoyed using the themes from the Report Builder, and the ability to pass the responsibility of the reports to my users.